# Laravel Passport Get Client ID By Access Token

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-passport

I'm writing a tiny sms gateway to be consumed by a couple of projects,

I implemented laravel passport authentication ([client credentials grant token](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport#client-credentials-grant-tokens))

Then I've added `CheckClientCredentials` to api middleware group:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
       ...
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        'bindings',
        \Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CheckClientCredentials::class
    ],
];
```

The logic is working fine, now in my controller I need to get client associated with a valid token.

**routes.php**

```
Route::post('/sms', function(Request $request) {
    // save the sms along with the client id and send it

    $client_id = ''; // get the client id somehow

    sendSms($request->text, $request->to, $client_id);
});
```

For obvious security reasons I can never send the client id with the consumer request e.g. `$client_id = $request->client_id;`.

Comment: Isn't `Auth::user()->token()->client->id` sufficient in your case?

Comment: @thijsai there is no user in client credentials grant token, it is used for  machine-to-machine authentication, each request i'm sending client id & secret token, then validating them on my endpoint, then grant the access, so the token is not stored on the client machine ...

Comment: Right, but correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't this what the JWT token is for?

Comment: If there is no user `Auth::user()` will return null, right? @thijsai

Comment: If the user set the JWT token and sends this along as access token, Passport will make sure that Auth::user() returns an actual user object. If you do not have an access token the client id it has to be sent along with the request for the access token.

Comment: @thijsai In machine-to-machine case, [no users associated with tokens](https://image.ibb.co/cO3yCw/Screen_Shot_2017_11_29_at_5_57_42_PM.png).

Comment: Try `$request->user()->token()->getAttribute('client_id')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, no answers ...

I was able to resolve the issue by consuming my own API, finally I came up with simpler authentication flow, the client need to send their id & secret with each request, then I consumed my own `/oauth/token` route with the sent credentials, inspired by *Esben Petersen* [blog post](http://esbenp.github.io/2017/03/19/modern-rest-api-laravel-part-4/).

Once the access token is generated, I append it to the headers of `Symfony\Request` instance which is under processing.

My final output like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Request;

use Closure;

class AddAccessTokenHeader
{
    /**
     * Octipus\ApiConsumer
     * @var ApiConsumer
     */
    private $apiConsumer;


    function __construct() {
        $this->apiConsumer  = app()->make('apiconsumer');
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $this->apiConsumer->post('/oauth/token', $request->input(), [
            'content-type' => 'application/json'
        ]);


        if (!$response->isSuccessful()) {
            return response($response->getContent(), 401)
                    ->header('content-type', 'application/json');
        }

        $response = json_decode($response->getContent(), true);

        $request->headers->add([
            'Authorization'     => 'Bearer ' . $response['access_token'],
            'X-Requested-With'  => 'XMLHttpRequest'
        ]);

        return $next($request);

    }
}
```

I used the above middleware in conjunction with Passport's `CheckClientCredentials`.

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        ...
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        'bindings',
        \App\Http\Middleware\AddAccessTokenHeader::class,
        \Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CheckClientCredentials::class
    ],
];
```

This way, I was able to insure that `$request->input('client_id')` is reliable and can't be faked.

Comment: How to call the others methods when send Bearer???please you can show the all code?

Comment: @Alexd2 what methods you want to call?

Comment: So you don't first obtain a client token, but always send client_id + secret? That's not how it's supposed to work.

Answer (score 15):

I use this, to access the authenticated client app...

```
$bearerToken = $request->bearerToken();
$tokenId = (new \Lcobucci\JWT\Parser())->parse($bearerToken)->getHeader('jti');
$client = \Laravel\Passport\Token::find($tokenId)->client;

$client_id = $client->id;
$client_secret = $client->secret;
```

[Source](https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/124#issuecomment-252434309)

Comment: This works for me but I'm having trouble finding a way to test it.  Even with the new Passport::actingAsClient($client) method, $request->bearerToken() doesn't get set to a valid JWT and I get a 500 error.

Comment: The token ID in the db is different from the actual token passed in the authorization header. Try `dd($bearerToken)` to confirm so.

Answer (score 10):

However the answer is quite late, i got some errors extracting the JTI header 
in Laravel 6.x because the JTI is no longer in the header, but only in the payload/claim. (Using client grants)

```php
local.ERROR: Requested header is not configured {"exception":"[object] (OutOfBoundsException(code: 0): Requested header is not configured at /..somewhere/vendor/lcobucci/jwt/src/Token.php:112)
```

Also, adding it in a middleware was not an option for me. As i needed it on several places in my app.

So i extended the original Laravel Passport Client (oauth_clients) model.
And check the header as well as the payload. Allowing to pass a request, or use
the request facade, if no request was passed.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request as RequestFacade;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Laravel\Passport\Client;
use Laravel\Passport\Token;
use Lcobucci\JWT\Parser;

class OAuthClient extends Client
{
    public static function findByRequest(?Request $request = null) : ?OAuthClient
    {
        $bearerToken = $request !== null ? $request->bearerToken() : RequestFacade::bearerToken();

        $parsedJwt = (new Parser())->parse($bearerToken);

        if ($parsedJwt->hasHeader('jti')) {
            $tokenId = $parsedJwt->getHeader('jti');
        } elseif ($parsedJwt->hasClaim('jti')) {
            $tokenId = $parsedJwt->getClaim('jti');
        } else {
            Log::error('Invalid JWT token, Unable to find JTI header');
            return null;
        }

        $clientId = Token::find($tokenId)->client->id;

        return (new static)->findOrFail($clientId);
    }
}
```

Now you can use it anywhere inside your laravel app like this:

If you have $request object available, (for example from a controller)

```php
$client = OAuthClient::findByRequest($request);
```

Or even if the request is not available somehow, you can use it without, like this:

```php
$client = OAuthClient::findByRequest();
```

Hopefully this useful for anyone, facing this issue today.

Answer (score 9):

There is a tricky method. 
You can modify the method of handle in the middleware CheckClientCredentials, just add this line.

```
        $request["oauth_client_id"] = $psr->getAttribute('oauth_client_id');
```

Then you can get client_id in controller's function:

```
public function info(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
{
    var_dump($request->oauth_client_id);
}
```

Comment: There was a pull request for laravel passport that has been dismissed: https://github.com/laravel/passport/pull/487

Comment: Nah, awesome! Thanks bud!

Comment: Where do you get `$psr` from? it's it injected into the controllers constructor?

Comment: This works, though I implemented a custom middleware that extends Laravel\Passport\CheckCilentCredentials and just overrides its handle() method.  I don't really like this long term, because it means that I won't keep up with changes to that function if it is updated in future releases, but it does work for now.

Answer (score 7):

The OAuth token and client information are stored as a **protected variable** in the Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens trait (which you add to your User model).

So simply add a getter method to your **User model** to expose the OAuth information:

```
public function get_oauth_client(){
  return $this->accessToken->client;
}
```

This will return an Eloquent model for the oauth_clients table

Comment: Great answer. The api has changed now however, and its: `$this->token->client`.

Comment: Client Credential is not linked to an User. That's not the type of auth he's asking help for.

Answer (score 4):

In the latest implementation you can use:

```
    use Laravel\Passport\Token;
    use Lcobucci\JWT\Configuration;
    
    $bearerToken = request()->bearerToken();
    $tokenId = Configuration::forUnsecuredSigner()->parser()->parse($bearerToken)->claims()->get('jti');
    $client = Token::find($tokenId)->client;
```

as suggested here: https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/124#issuecomment-784731969

Answer (score 3):

I dug into CheckClientCredentials class and extracted what I needed to get the `client_id` from the token. `aud` claim is where the `client_id` is stored.

```
<?php
    Route::middleware('client')->group(function() {
        Route::get('/client-id', function (Request $request) {
            $jwt = trim(preg_replace('/^(?:\s+)?Bearer\s/', '', $request->header('authorization')));
            $token = (new \Lcobucci\JWT\Parser())->parse($jwt);

            return ['client_id' => $token->getClaim('aud')];
        });
    });
```

Few places to refactor this to in order to easily access but that will be up to your application

Comment: I used this method in a custom middleware. I'd rather not modify passport source in my project so this worked the best.

Answer (score 3):

As I can see the above answer **are old** and most importantly it dose not work with **laravel 8 and php 8**, so I have found a way to get the client id of the access token ( current request )

the answer is basically making a middleware, and add it to all routes you want to get the client id.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Nyholm\Psr7\Factory\Psr17Factory;
use Laravel\Passport\TokenRepository;
use League\OAuth2\Server\ResourceServer;
use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;
use League\OAuth2\Server\Exception\OAuthServerException;
use Symfony\Bridge\PsrHttpMessage\Factory\PsrHttpFactory;

class SetPassportClient
{

    /**
     * The Resource Server instance.
     *
     * @var \League\OAuth2\Server\ResourceServer
     */
    protected $server;

    /**
     * Token Repository.
     *
     * @var \Laravel\Passport\TokenRepository
     */
    protected $repository;

    /**
     * Create a new middleware instance.
     *
     * @param  \League\OAuth2\Server\ResourceServer  $server
     * @param  \Laravel\Passport\TokenRepository  $repository
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(ResourceServer $server, TokenRepository $repository)
    {
        $this->server = $server;
        $this->repository = $repository;
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $psr = (new PsrHttpFactory(
            new Psr17Factory,
            new Psr17Factory,
            new Psr17Factory,
            new Psr17Factory
        ))->createRequest($request);

        try {
            $psr = $this->server->validateAuthenticatedRequest($psr);
        } catch (OAuthServerException $e) {
            throw new AuthenticationException;
        }
        
        $token = $this->repository->find($psr->getAttribute('oauth_access_token_id'));

        if (!$token)
            abort(401);

        $request->merge(['passportClientId' => $token->client_id]);

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Add the middleware to *app\Http\Kernel.php*

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    .
    .
    'passport.client.set' => \App\Http\Middleware\SetPassportClient::class
];
```

Finaly in the routes add the middleware

```
Route::middleware(['client', 'passport.client.set'])->get('/test-client-id', function (Request $request){
 dd($request->passportClientId); // this the client id
});
```

Sorry for the long answer, but I want it to be very clear to any all.

All of the code was inspired by laravel [CheckCredentials.php](https://github.com/laravel/passport/blob/10.x/src/Http/Middleware/CheckCredentials.php)

Answer (score 2):

in laravel version 10

you can get the client and the user information using the following code

```
$client = auth('api')->client();
$user = User::findOrFail($client->user_id);
```

I am using Client Credentials Grant Tokens OAuth type
[here is the Laravel official Client Credentials Grant Tokens documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/passport#client-credentials-grant-tokens:%7E:text=define%20this%20route.-,Client%20Credentials%20Grant%20Tokens,-The%20client%20credentials)

Comment: Just leaving a short code to help 

`Route::middleware('client')->get('/verify', function (Request $request) {    
    $client = auth('api')->client();
    return $client;
)};`

Answer (score 0):

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $scope)
{
    if (!empty($scope)) {
        $psr      = (new DiactorosFactory)->createRequest($request);
        $psr      = $this->server->validateAuthenticatedRequest($psr);
        $clientId = $psr->getAttribute('oauth_client_id');
        $request['oauth_client_id'] = intval($clientId);
       }

    return $next($request);
}
```

put above to your middleware file, then you can access client_id by `request()->oauth_client_id`

Answer (score -1):

In a method you can easily get by:

```
$token = $request->user()->token();

$clientId = $token['client_id'];
```

Comment: you may need to add some error handling to this code to make it more robust. for example what if $request()->user()->token() is undefined?

Comment: Middleware "auth:api" already does this. You'd never get to this point unless you are authenticated.